# Convert XML to C# Dictionary

Tags: xml, linq, dictionary

I've got an XML response that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <scheme>
    <name>name_1</name>
    <items>
      <item>
        <itemid>testid_1</itemid>
        <new></new>
        <used></used>
      </item>
      <item>
        <itemid>testid_2</itemid>
        <new></new>
        <used></used>
      </item>
    </items>
  </scheme>
  <scheme>
    <name>name_2</name>
    <items>
      <item>
        <itemid>testid_3</itemid>
        <new></new>
        <used></used>
      </item>
    </items>
  </scheme>
</response>
```

I've got to convert this XML response into a `Dictionary<string, List<Item>>`. Each entry in the dictionary is a `<scheme>` element, where the Dictionary's key is the `<name>` node, and the Dictionary's value is the `List<Item>`, where the `Item` object is comprised of `itemid`, `new`, and `used`.

So far I've got code that looks like:

```
var items =
            from item in itemsXml.Descendants("scheme")
            select new Item
            {
                ItemId = item.Element("itemid").Value,
                New = item.Element("new").Value,
                Used = item.Element("used").Value,
            };
```

So the code I've got above will create me a list of Item, but how do I get access to the `<name>` node in each `<scheme>` node? Again, the `<name>` is the key, and the `List<Item>` under each scheme is the value for my Dictionary.

Any suggestions on a different way to do this??!? I'm definitely not doing this right..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var dict = xml.Elements("scheme")
              .ToDictionary(e => e.Element("name").Value,
                            e => e.Descendants("item")
                                  .Select(item => new Item()
                                  {
                                      ItemId = item.Element("itemid").Value,
                                      New = item.Element("new").Value,
                                      Used = item.Element("used").Value
                                  }).ToList()
                           );
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but it xml.Elements("scheme") is NULL. It should be noted that the xml element is of type XDocument.

Comment: if i spit out the contents of the XDocument, i get:
<response>
  <scheme>
    <name>category_rr</name>
    <items>
      <item>
        <itemid></itemid>
        <new></new>
        <used></used>
      </item>
    </items>
  </scheme>
  <pageid>res11040714675342229509419</pageid>
</response>

Comment: I've changed the initial xml.Elements("scheme") to xml.Descendants("scheme") and that fixed everything. Thanks!

Comment: @Shafique for an `XDocument` you need to access the `Root` property: `xml.Root.Elements("scheme")...`

Comment: @AhmadMageed can youplese help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146447/linq-to-xml-with-nested-dictionary-and-array#comment33605276_22146447

Answer (score 2):

Does it HAVE to be a dictionary?

The reason I'm asking is, you could create an item class that has your item properties.
Then create a scheme class that has a property called "Name" as well as a List property.

You could then use .NET deserialization to create a list of schemes, each scheme having a list of items.

Something like:

```
public class Response
{
    public IList<Scheme> Schemes {get; set;}
}

public class Scheme
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IList<Item> Items {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemId {get; set;}
    public bool New {get; set;}
    public bool Used {get; set;}
}
```

Then follow a tutorial like this one: http://sharpertutorials.com/serialization/
And let .Net do the deserialization for you.

Granted, this won't work if you have to do a dictionary.

Comment: Serialization is "creative"?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Nope, I think it's pretty boring.

Comment: Well, I thought it was creative to come up with something that wasn't the stock `ToDictionary` answer, and still could be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need a Dictionary<string, List<myObject>>