# Linq to XML with nested Dictionary and Array

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, parsing, windows-phone-8

I am Working on Windows Phone 8 application:

I have a document like this :

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>SubTopics</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>CD1</string>
                    <string>CD2</string>
                    <string>CD3</string>
                    <string>CD4</string>    
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Miscellaneous</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>DDC1</string>
                    <string>DDC2</string>
                    <string>DDC3</string>
                    <string>DDC4</string>
                    <string>DDC5</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Miscellaneous One</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
      </array>
      <key>MainTitle</key>
      <string>Data</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>SubTopics</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>SSD1</string>
                    <string>SS2</string>
                    <string>SS3</string>
                    <string>SS4</string>    
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Goblins</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>ADC1</string>
                    <string>ADC2</string>
                    <string>ADC3</string>
                    <string>ADC4</string>
                    <string>DDC5</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Tracks</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
      </array>
      <key>MainTitle</key>
      <string>Data Two</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

How to parse this ?

Its like this :

```
MainTitle 

   --SubTitle

  ---ID

  ---Desc

  ---Boolean Value
 MainTitle 

   --SubTitle

  ---ID

  ---Desc

  ---Boolean Value
```

Basically a List of Dictionary with Key and Array list of values.

I have tried like this but its not complete:

```
List<MyObject> topics = (from plist in doc.Root.Element("array").Elements("dict")
                                  select new MyObject
                                  {
                                      MainTitle = (string)plist.Element("string"),
                                      ListOfSubTitles = plist.Element("array")
                                                   .Elements("dict")
                                                   .Elements("string")
                                                   .Select(s => (string)s)
                                                   .ToList(),
                                      ListOfIDs = plist.Element("array")
                                                    .Elements("dict")
                                                    .Elements("array")
                                                    .Elements("string")
                                                    .Select(s => (string)s)
                                                    .ToList()
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your xml  is not good because it assumes some specific order of elements `key,value,key,value....`. If you don't get it from an  external site, change it...

Comment: @L.B No its proper, i have parsed the same Xml in JAVA, just i am stuck how to do it in c#

Comment: Goofy, I don't say it is invalid, I say, It is a bad practice to count on order of elements in xml. A better way would be a list of `<KeyValue><Key>...</Key><Value>....</Value></KeyValue>`

Comment: @L.B yes, but i have to go with this,there is no other option, can you please help me?

Comment: That is a pList file from iOS - he is converting an iPhone app to Windows - just like me - thanks for asking the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a little class that can parse your xml:

```
public class Parser
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Parse(XElement root)
    {
        var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (var e in root.Elements())
        {
            if (e.Name == "dict")
            {
                result.Add(ParseDict(e));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> ParseDict(XElement element)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var subelement in element.Elements())
        {
            if (subelement.Name == "key")
            {
                dict.Add(subelement.Value, ParseValue(subelement.ElementsAfterSelf().First()));        
            }
        }

        return dict;
    }

    private object ParseValue(XElement valueElement)
    {
        if (valueElement.Name == "string")
        {
            return valueElement.Value;
        }

        if (valueElement.Name == "array")
        {
            return new List<object>(valueElement.Elements().Select(e => ParseValue(e)));
        }

        if (valueElement.Name == "dict")
        {
            return ParseDict(valueElement);
        }

        if (valueElement.Name == "true")
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (valueElement.Name == "false")
        {
            return false;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It is used like this:

```
        var parser = new Parser();
        var doc = XDocument.Load(<path to xml file>);

        var result = parser.Parse(doc.Root);
```

The parser is very crude and makes assumptions about the xml. And as pointed out in earlier comments, it is not the best way to use xml like this, where position of elements has significance. Also the use of "object" in the parser isn't a good solution, but the parser gets a lot more advanced if you want to avoid that.

Comment: But here how will i get the ListOfSubTitles by using MainTitle  ? or ListOfIDs  for ListOfSubTitles ?, i mean based on key i need vlaues

Comment: Because of the format of your xml, you can't really parse it in that way. You need to iterate through the element and save data along the way. You could either use XDocument or XmlReader for this. There would take some time to create a working example, so that have to wait until I'm off work.

Comment: Don't worry about the parser being crude, this is a one off task at app startup to load data. It is a really important part of the process of converting from iOS to Windows for many apps. iOS pList files all look like that so your solution has very wide use. I have added a little code snippet in another answer below to enable people to test the output.

Answer (score 0):

I used Hakan's Parser class almost straight out of the box: I needed an integer element but no true or false - simple edits. This snippet might help people test their code. I have renamed some of Hakan's symbols to fit my project.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> topicsList = topicParser.Parse(topicsXDocument.Root);
        Console.WriteLine("The Topics List contains:");
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> topic in topicsList)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> element in topic)
            {
                string name = element.Key;
                object content = element.Value;
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", name, content.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```